# ServiceStack: Pass an array to a Service

Tags: servicestack

I'm having an issue when I pass an array to my service, it only recognizes the first value in the array:

Here is my request object:

```
[Route("/dashboard", "GET")]
public class DashboardRequest : IReturn<Dashboard>
{
    public int[] EquipmentIds { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the request which is made:

```
http://localhost:9090/json/reply/DashboardRequest?EquipmentIds=1&EquipmentIds=2
```

But when I observe the array in my service, it only contains one value, which is `1`.

```
public object Get(DashboardRequest request)
{
    // request.EquipmentIds.Length == 1;
    // request.EquipmentIds[0] == 1;
}
```

One Solution I've done is the following, which seems a bit hacky? I thought the point of specifying it in my Request Object is that I get a strongly typed Request Object?

```
var equipmentIds = Request
                       .QueryString["EquipmentIds"]
                       .Split(',')
                       .Select(int.Parse)
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: Why don't you do `http://localhost:9090/json/reply/DashboardRequest?EquipmentIds=1,2,3`?

Comment: Its how my request was constructed when using `params` with `$http.get` using angular: `$http.get(baseUri + "DashboardRequest", { params: { EquipmentIds: selectedEquipmentIds } })`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works when you use the custom route, e.g:

```
[Route("/dashboard", "GET")]
public class DashboardRequest : IReturn<Dashboard>
{
    public int[] EquipmentIds { get; set; }
}
```

and call it via the User Defined route, e.g:

```
http://localhost:9090/dashboard?EquipmentIds=1&EquipmentIds=2
```

Support for this has also been added on [Predefined Routes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#pre-defined-routes) in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/b91566b579142c85780bf6de2fe8f083022f9434) which will be available from **v4.0.24+** that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

So your existing request now works as well, e.g:

```
http://localhost:9090/json/reply/DashboardRequest?EquipmentIds=1&EquipmentIds=2
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind the request object to the int array like

```
[Route("/dashboard/{EquipmentIds}", "GET")]
public class DashboardRequest : IReturn<Dashboard>
{
    public int[] EquipmentIds { get; set; }
}

 http://localhost:9090/dashboard/1,2
```

Comment: Besides this code doesn't populate the `EquipmentIds`, and results in `null`. The existing comments already state that AngularJS is dictating the format of the request which requires to send the `EquipmentIds` parameters separated in the query string. Like `EquipmentIds=1&EquipmentIds=2`.

Comment: I think you probably meant `http://localhost:9090/dashboard/1,2` but as mentioned this is not the format the OP is able to send the request as.

Comment: Correct, when I do `/dashboard?EquipmentIds=1,2,3` it binds correctly, but when I do `/dashboard?EquipmentIds=1&EquipmentIds=2` it doesn't so I have to use the solution I mentioned in my question. It must be the way the text serialzation is working

Comment: Works in version 3.9